# Execution failed for task ':app:signReleaseBundle' during flutter build appbundle command. I get an error

Tags: flutter, dart, jks, app-bundle

My key.properties file:

```
storePassword=123456
keyPassword=123456
keyAlias=key
storeFile=C:\\Users\\asus\\Desktop\\key.jks
```

First warning:

[image]

Second warning:

[image]

*The key.jks file is created, but when I enter the appbundle command, I get an error.*

Comment: keyAlias is wrong

Comment: what is the truth? Do I need to add the extension?

Comment: No you only need to correct the name of keyAlias or you can create you new key if you forgot what is the name of keyAlias

Comment: "keytool -genkey -v -keystore C:\Users\asus\Desktop\key.jks -storetype JKS -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias upload" I created a key named key.jks using this command. Isn't KeyAlias the "key" here?

Comment: alias is upload